# Uipath exchange activity

Tags: exchangewebservices, uipath, robotic-scraping

In uipath there is a get exchange messages activity. I can connect and download messages, however I'm unsure of the syntax for getting to a shared mailbox. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around it by building a powershell script to do it, then calling it from uipath...

Comment: Hi, can you share your powershell script?
It will help others that have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in Exchange it's not possible to get the messages from a shared mailbox with UiPath Exchange activities but it's possible with Outlook activities.